# MySQL automatically updating field when inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm making a web application to make customers order items for anything. For that I've made  a MySQL database which has the following tables:

- `customers`
- `orders`
- `orders-items`
- `products`

In the `customers` table is all the information about the person such as:

- The customer ID, for the primary key and auto increment (id)
- The first name (first_name)
- The last name (last_name)
- The email address (email_address)
- Information about the customer (customer_info)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `orders` table is all the specific information about it such as:

- The order ID, for the primary key and auto increment (id)
- Which customer it ordered, linked with `id` field from the `customers` table (customer_id)
- Order information (order_info)
- The location where the order needs to go to (location)
- The total price the customer has to pay (total_price)
- When the order was created (created)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `orders-items` table are all the items which every customer ordered, this is being linked by the `order-id` from the previous table.

- The ID, for primary key and auto increment, not used for any relation (id)
- The order ID, used for which product is for which order. This is linked with the `id` field from the `orders` table (order_id)
- The product ID, this is used for what product they ordered, this is linked with the id field from the `products` table. (product_id)
- The amount of this product they ordered (quantity)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `products` table is all the information about the products:

- The ID, for primary key and auto incrementing, This is linked with the `product_id` field from the `order_items` table (id)
- The name of the product (name)
- The description of the product (description)
- The price of the product (price)

**Example:**

[image]

**Question:**

I've got this query:

```
SELECT `orders-items`.`order_id` , SUM(`orders-items`.`quantity`* `products`.`price`) total
FROM  `orders-items` 
INNER JOIN  `Products` ON  `orders-items`.`products_id` =  `products`.`id`
```

And it shows me a list of all the total prices every `order_id` has to pay.

But how do I make this so that this value of the `total_price` every `order_id` has to pay is automatticly inserted into the `orders` table inside the `total_price` field at the right `order_id` when inserting a product into my `orders-list` table?

Or is it still better to not keep track of the `total_prices` the `customers` have to pay?

Comment: I do not store the total amount due until the final checkout/payment, as it changes often with adding/removing items. You could keep the total, but it would require a second query everytime you add/remove an item, or you could set a mysql `trigger` to update the cart total everytime the items change.

Comment: You may have already considered this, but how will you handle it in the future when the price of an item changes? Will you add a new record to the items table in which everything is the same except the price, or will you update the price of the existing record? If you change the price by updating, your `SUM` query will no longer be accurate for old orders, and you will need to add price to your orders-items table to keep track of the price of the item at the time of the order.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I hoped when i changed a price of an item, it didnt update anything from the the orders total_price in the past. Only when i a add a new one. Or What do you mean?

Comment: @Sean But is this still a good way to keep track of the total_price the customer have to pay? And how would i do that then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things to consider.

Having a `total_price` for itself is redundant. You can learn this total by summing the prices of this order's items at any time. It might be interesting to have it for performance reasons, but is this really necessary for your scenario? It rarely is.

Having a `price` on each `order_item` in the other hand would be useful. And the why is because thoses products prices might change in the future and you don't want to lose information of for how much they were sold at the time of that particular sale.

In any case, you can update your `total_price` using triggers like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER order_items_insert AFTER INSERT ON `orders-items` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE orders o INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price FROM `orders-items` i INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id AND i.order_id = new.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id SET o.total_price = t.total_price;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER order_items_update AFTER UPDATE ON `orders-items` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE orders o INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price FROM `orders-items` i INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id AND i.order_id = new.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id SET o.total_price = t.total_price;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER order_items_delete AFTER DELETE ON `orders-items` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE orders o INNER JOIN (SELECT i.order_id id, SUM(i.quantity * p.price) total_price FROM `orders-items` i INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = i.products_id AND i.order_id = old.order_id) t ON t.id = o.id SET o.total_price = t.total_price;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When i'm trying to `insert` a new record into the `orders-items` table, it gives me a `Invalid use of group function` error message.. This is the query i'm trying to run: `INSERT INTO `broodjes-service`.`orders-items` (`id`, `order_id`, `products_id`, `quantity`) VALUES (NULL, '3', '3', '3')`

Comment: i figured out its this part wich is not working correctly: `SET o.total_price = sum(i.quantity * p.price)`. Whenever i replace the whole `sum` with just another value. it gets inserted on the right place. but the sum isnt working.

Comment: Try with `GROUP BY o.id`, it might fix the sum.

Comment: That didnt work, but i did abit of research, and when i used a subquery it did work. Its like this now: `SET o.`total_price` = (SELECT sum(i.quantity * p.price))
` Is that alright to? Btw, when i'm trying to install the `trigger` for delete, it gives me this error:

UPDATE orders o
   INNER JOIN `orders-items` i ON o.id = i.order_id
   INNER JOIN `products` p ON p.id = i.products_id 

`#1363 - There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger`

Is there anything i can do about that aswell? I dont even get it what its saying.

Comment: Oh, on delete use `old.id` instead of `new.id`

Comment: Thank you for that :) but can you explain abit more about the `GROUP BY ....` you just said? (Thats not working btw) Or is my method better (while im still not really sure what im actually doing)

Comment: `GROUP BY` will tell which group should be summed, but this should be implicit since there is only one `order.id` being handled. Not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: We can try this without `WHERE`, placing the condition elsewhere. I changed the query, try the new one.

Comment: Sorry but this gave me exactly the same error about the invalid use of group function, when using your updated answer code.

Comment: Thank you, that does it. Can you explain me what you did though? I dont get anything from it haha. Or actually, what was the problem?

Comment: Not sure what was the problem, but aparently the use of group functions are limited on `UPDATE`, so I pushed it to a subquery. Subqueries are usually bad for performance, but in this case it will be returning only one row so it should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

One Option would be a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html), which is executed on inserting a new customer.

Alternative you could going for a [`stored procedure`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html). With this, you only need to call the procedure `InsertCustomer`, and the database handles the price update for you -> you will not have these dependencies in your Application.

Another way could be, to do 2 querys (insert and update) in a `transaction`. But for this i recommend [`Domain Driven Design`](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=97). You would have a service, which has the method `CreateCustomer(Customer $customer)`, which do a insert query and then the update query. On success it commits the transaction and returns true, if not success, it cancel the transaction and reuturns false. It should be your own convention to only manipulate data with help of the services (which knows the business logic).

Comment: For me it would be the combination of two ( a trigger to call the stored procedure ).